# confusion in choosing tomcat docker image for cloud run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

hey I am new to docker and I want to deploy my tomcat application on cloud run , so I need to choose an image which is slim and my second question is do I need to install Java or jdk with it if I choose
tomcat:9-slim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explore the container content. For instance, go to [that page](https://hub.docker.com/layers/tomcat/library/tomcat/9-slim/images/sha256-75c2d815b1cf9eb1c8dc31640edc53ca0a8204af0fb3c5c657fe47fc143432c8?context=explore) and you can see that openjdk-11 is installed. No need to install another version (expect if you need a more recent version.